# Flutter - Custom Widget - How to obtain a value from

Tags: flutter, widget

This is a simple example of the problem that I have. Given the following example, how can I obtain the value of "counter" from outside the Class?

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterState createState() => _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int counter = 0;
  void increaseCount() {
    setState(() => this.counter++);
    print("New count = $counter");
  }

  Widget build(context) {
    return new RaisedButton(
      onPressed: increaseCount,
      child: new Text('Tap To Add'),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In Flutter what you normally do is to pass a callback function, in that function you can pass the value you need, e.g.

```
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  // you can use a callback function
  final ValueSetter<int> callback;

  Counter({this.callback});

  @override
  _CounterState createState() => _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int counter = 0;
  void increaseCount() {
    setState(() => this.counter++);
    print("New count = $counter");
    // Here you can pass the value
    widget.callback(this.counter);
  }

  Widget build(context) {
    return new RaisedButton(
      onPressed: increaseCount,
      child: new Text('Tap To Add'),
    );
  }
}
```

And when calling your widget, you do as follow:

```
Counter(callback: (counter){
      // Here you can take some actions on counter
    });
```

This is the most simple way I know, or you can use some other patterns like bloc or something else.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks, I'll study that, but what I want is for the Widget to have its own state and for me to get it when I want it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a GlobalKey like this:

```dart
class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  final globalKey = GlobalKey<_CounterState>();

  @override
  _CounterState createState() => _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int counter = 0;
  void increaseCount() {
    setState(() => counter++);
    print("New count = $counter");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return RaisedButton(
      onPressed: increaseCount,
      child: Text('Tap To Add'),
    );
  }
}
```

and access the counter like this:

```dart
Counter counter = Counter();
int count = counter.globalKey.currentState.counter;
```

A word of caution: This is **not** recommended.

You're transitioning from a simple, contained state to a state which is shared between several widgets. There are several better ways to address this problem. For further information and better ways to deal with the problem visit https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt .

Comment: Please look at my answer and comment if you care to. If there is an easier way to achieve that I would like to know. I presume that if your solution is not recommended then there is a reason for that.

Comment: The answer from Hosar is the easiest solution for your use-case. Thats called "lifting state up". The flutter.dev-Link (especially this site: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) shows you how to do that and what alternatives there are.

Comment: I tried Hosar's method, and it appears to me to do what I expected. It provides a callback that provides the value when it changes. I don't want that. What I want is for the Widget to have state and give me the value when I ask for it. In that way I don't have to have unstructured variables in my program to store the value of Widgets. When it comes to update the data I can get the value from the Widget (sole-source-of-truth). I'm not saying what I have done is the best way to do it, but it does achieve what I want - a Widget with its own state. The Widget has the value in any case.

Comment: I will have a look at scoped_model to see what it does. As I see it, TextEditingController currently has its own state. That means that I don't have to store the value of the text in my program. All I need to do is check if the data has changed. If it has changed, I allow an update and get the values from the TextEditingController. I have applied this same concept to the Checkbox in a similar way to the CounterWithState that I have written.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply an example (proof-of-concept) to demonstrate what I want to achieve. I simply want the Widget to store its value and to give it to me when I want it (ie. to update data). The alternative is for the main program to store the value, but I don't think that is ideal.

The following appears to work. It seems top me like a lot to do to simply obtain the value of the counter. I hope that there is an easier way. Code is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'counterWithState.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  CounterWithState _counterWithState =
      CounterWithState(iCounter: 0, isAllowedChange: true);
  FloatingActionButton _fab;
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fab = FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _showSnackbar,
      tooltip: 'Press to show Counter',
      child: Icon(Icons.info),
    );
  }

  _showSnackbar() {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        content:
            Text("Current value of Counter is ${_counterWithState.iCounter}")));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _counterWithState.getCounterWidget(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _fab,
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CounterWithState {
  int _iCounter;
  CounterWithStateInternal _counterWithStateInternal;

  fnDataChanged(int iNewCounter) {
    _iCounter = iNewCounter;
    debugPrint("CounterWithState: New value = $_iCounter");
  }

  CounterWithStateInternal getCounterWidget() {
    return _counterWithStateInternal;
  }

  CounterWithState({@required iCounter, @required bool isAllowedChange}) {
    _iCounter = iCounter;
    _counterWithStateInternal = CounterWithStateInternal(
        GlobalKey(), this._iCounter, isAllowedChange, fnDataChanged);
  }
  get iCounter => _iCounter;
}

class CounterWithStateInternal extends StatefulWidget {
  final int iCounter;
  final bool tfAllowChange;
  final Function fnDataChanged;
  CounterWithStateInternal(
      Key key, this.iCounter, this.tfAllowChange, this.fnDataChanged)
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  CounterWithStateMain createState() => CounterWithStateMain();
}

class CounterWithStateMain extends State<CounterWithStateInternal> {
  int _iCounter = 0;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _iCounter = widget.iCounter;
  }

  void increaseCount() {
    if (widget.tfAllowChange) {
      setState(() => this._iCounter++);
      widget.fnDataChanged(_iCounter);
      print("CounterWithStateMain: New count = $_iCounter");
    }
  }

  Widget build(context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Text("Value of counter = $_iCounter"),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20.0,
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: increaseCount,
        child: Text('Tap To Add'),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach, for doing the same there are too many other solutions. And the title of your question is misleading. As you can see in your OWN code your want to manipulate the STATE (CounterWithState), not just to get the value.

Comment: @Hosar. Can't see how you conclude that. I want the Widget to have state and to get the value when I want it (at update). Please elaborate because your comment makes no sense to me. If there is another way then show me. I don't want to manipulate anything, I just want to be able to get the value (CounterWithState). "Too many other solutions"???

Answer (score 0):

This is an update of my previous answer to better illustrate what I want to achieve. I am currently using this concept in my code using a Checkbox to store its own value.

This is simply an example (proof-of-concept) to demonstrate what I want to achieve. I simply want the Widget to store its value and to give it to me when I want it (ie. to update data). The alternative is for the main program to store the value, but I don't think that is ideal.

The following appears to work. It seems top me like a lot to do to simply obtain the value of the counter. I hope that there is an easier way. Code is below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'counterWithState.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String sTitle = 'Flutter Counter-With-State Demo';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: sTitle,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: sTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  CounterWithState _counterWithState;
  FloatingActionButton _fab;
  int _iCounterOriginal = 99;
  RaisedButton _raisedButton;
  SizedBox _sizedBox;
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fab = FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: _showSnackbar,
      tooltip: 'Press to show Counter',
      child: Icon(Icons.info),
    );
    _raisedButton = RaisedButton(
        child: const Text('Update'),
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        elevation: 4.0,
        splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        onPressed: () {
          _iCounterOriginal = _counterWithState.iCounter;
          _counterWithState = null;
          _getCounterWithState(context);
          setState(() {});
        });
    _sizedBox = SizedBox(height: _raisedButton.height);
  }

  fnCounterChanged(int iCounter) {
    setState(() {});
  }

  _showSnackbar() {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        content:
            Text("Current value of Counter is ${_counterWithState.iCounter}")));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _counterWithState = _counterWithState != null
        ? _counterWithState
        : _getCounterWithState(context);
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _counterWithState.getCounterWidget(),
            _getUpdateButton(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: _fab,
    );
  }

  Widget _getUpdateButton(BuildContext context) {
    return _counterWithState == null ||
            _counterWithState.iCounter == _iCounterOriginal
        ? _sizedBox
        : _raisedButton;
  }

  CounterWithState _getCounterWithState(context) {
    if (_counterWithState == null)
      _counterWithState = CounterWithState(
          iCounter: _iCounterOriginal,
          isAllowedChange: true,
          fnNotifyChange: fnCounterChanged);
    return _counterWithState;
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CounterWithState {
  int _iCounter;
  final Function fnNotifyChange;
  CounterWithStateInternal _counterWithStateInternal;

  fnDataChanged(int iNewCounter) {
    _iCounter = iNewCounter;
    if (fnNotifyChange != null) fnNotifyChange(iNewCounter);
  }

  CounterWithStateInternal getCounterWidget() {
    return _counterWithStateInternal;
  }

  CounterWithState(
      {@required iCounter,
      @required bool isAllowedChange,
      this.fnNotifyChange}) {
    _iCounter = iCounter;
    _counterWithStateInternal = CounterWithStateInternal(
        GlobalKey(), this._iCounter, isAllowedChange, fnDataChanged);
  }
  get iCounter => _iCounter;
}

class CounterWithStateInternal extends StatefulWidget {
  final int iCounter;
  final bool tfAllowChange;
  final Function fnDataChanged;
  CounterWithStateInternal(
      Key key, this.iCounter, this.tfAllowChange, this.fnDataChanged)
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  CounterWithStateMain createState() => CounterWithStateMain();
}

class CounterWithStateMain extends State<CounterWithStateInternal> {
  int _iCounter;
  int _iOriginalCounter;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _iCounter = widget.iCounter;
    _iOriginalCounter = widget.iCounter;
  }

  void incrementCounter(int iValue) {
    if (widget.tfAllowChange) {
      setState(() => this._iCounter += iValue);
      widget.fnDataChanged(_iCounter);
    }
  }

  Widget build(context) {
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      Text("Value of original counter = $_iOriginalCounter"),
      _getSizedBox(),
      Text("Value of counter = $_iCounter"),
      _getSizedBox(),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: (() => incrementCounter(1)),
        child: Text('Tap To Add'),
      ),
      _getSizedBox(),
      RaisedButton(
        onPressed: (() => incrementCounter(-1)),
        child: Text('Tap To Subtract'),
      ),
      _getSizedBox(),
    ]);
  }

  SizedBox _getSizedBox() {
    return SizedBox(height: 20.0);
  }
}
```